# Proper way to throw error from my closure?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm actually trying to some code logic with swift for training purpose at the moment, I was wondering what is the proper way to throw my error from my init ?

So the flow is Controller ask for account creation when initializing Model is asking my sql manager to create the account and this method return the result from a closure.

But something feels wrong, should I just use a return from the sql manager who contained both my Int? and Error? ?

```
init(_ username: String, _ password: String) throws {
        self.id = 0
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

        var toThrow: Error? = nil
        // Register in database
        userManager.create(self) { (id: Int?, err: Error?) in
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10)
            if let error = err {

                // Register in database goes wrong
                debugPrint("Handle error from user creation...")
                toThrow = error
            } else {

                // There is no id and no error ?
                guard let _ = id else { return }
                self.id = id!
            }
        }

        if let error = toThrow {
            throw error
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Swift 5 you could look into using Result and define your closure like

```
(id: Int) -> Result<Int, Error>
```

and change your code to

```
userManager.create(self) { (id: Int?) -> Result<Int, Error> in
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10)
        if let error = err {

            // Register in database goes wrong
            debugPrint("Handle error from user creation...")
            return .failure(error)
        } else {

            // There is no id and no error ?
            guard let _ = id else { return }
            return .success(id)
        }
    }
```

If you have your own error enum for the Db class like

```
enum DbError {
    case create
    case update
    //...
}
```

Then you can use that type in the closure declaration

```
(id: Int?) -> Result<Int, DbError>
```

and return a specific error for this action

```
 return .failure(.create)
```

Note that I haven't compiled this so consider it an example

Comment: @bornZaim You create a user in an init method, which I don't know the reason for, so in this situation I think it is best to throw but if/when calling userManager.create from other parts in the code it might be better to display the alert directly afterwards or returning it.

Comment: Yea I was trying in this case, but yea a separate method to register the new user in db would be more practical

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution if people want to see:

```
@IBAction func didPressRegister() {
        guard let username = usernameField.text else { return }
        guard let password = passwordField.text else { return }

        let user = UserModel(username, password)
        userManager.create(user) { result in
            switch(result) {
            case .failure(let error):
                // TODO: UIAlert
                debugPrint(error)
            case .success(let int):
                // TODO: Generate user token and redirect main
                debugPrint(int)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
// TODO
    public func create(_ user: UserModel, _ complete: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>) -> ()) {

        debugPrint("Requested to create the user... \(user)")
        complete(.failure(toThrow.ACCOUNT_ERROR))
    }
```